# How to search if 2 sets of strings are present in a different string in an if statement?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I want to search for two sets of strings in a string in an if statement but I'm not sure how to do that. As of now this is what I've typed:

```
description0=(driver.find_element_by_id('vjs-content').text)
    for mark in markerfile:
       if mark in description0.split():
```

Basically I want to search for mark and mark.swapcase() in description0.split() without adding another for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have multiple methods to find a string inside another string built in python. I would suggest doing the following:

```
string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..."

for substring in list:
    if string.find(substring) != -1:
        doWhatever()
```

Here, the `.find()` method has takes a substring and searches for it in its parent string. If it finds it, it will return the index of where your substring starts in the original string. If it doesn't find it, it will return a -1.

I suppose your indentation error on the code you provided was unintentional. For more information on this topic, I would suggest checking out this tutorial:
https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-string-contains?utm_source=adwords_ppc&utm_campaignid=898687156&utm_adgroupid=48947256715&utm_device=c&utm_keyword=&utm_matchtype=b&utm_network=g&utm_adpostion=&utm_creative=229765585183&utm_targetid=aud-299261629574:dsa-429603003980&utm_loc_interest_ms=&utm_loc_physical_ms=20291&gclid=CjwKCAjwjJmIBhA4EiwAQdCbxsxaYGPQT4dfSTovJRjb2rtovRaH9YDk6zeCvNzIcLztlQkWBggx8RoCFkkQAvD_BwE

Please, don't forget to mark your question as answered, and hope it helped!